# Economy Producer/Consumer Simulation

Tags: simulation, directed-acyclic-graphs, consumer, producer, max-flow

Hello wonderful community!

I'm currently writing a small game in my spare time.  It takes place in a large galaxy, where the player has control of some number of **Stars**.  On these stars you can construct **Buildings**, each of which has some number (0..*) of inputs, and produce some number of outputs.  These buildings have a maximum capacity/throughput, and scaling down it's inputs scales down it's outputs by an equal amount.  I'd like to find a budgeting algorithm that optimizes (or approximates) the throughput of all the buildings.  It seems like some kind of max-flow problem, but none of the flow optimization algorithms I've read have differing types of inputs or dependent outputs.

The toy "tech tree" I've been playing with is:

```
Solar plant - None => 2 energy output.
Extractor   - 1 energy => 1 ore output
Refinery    - 1 energy, 1 ore => 1 metal
Shipyard    - 1 metal, 2 energy => 1 ship
```

I'm willing to accept sub-optimal algorithms, and I'm willing to make the guarantee that the inputs/outputs have no cycles (they form a DAG from building to building).  The idea is to allow reasonable throughput and tech tree complexity, without player intervention, because on the scale of hundreds or thousands of stars, allowing the player to manually define the budgeting strategy isn't fun and gives players who no-life it a distinct advantage.

My current strategy is to build up a DAG, and give the resources a total ordering (Ships are better than Metal is better than Ore is better than energy), then, looping through each of the resources, find the most "descendant" building which produces that resource, allow it to greedily grab from it's inputs recursively (a shipyard would take 2 energy, and 1 metal, and then the refinery would grab 1 energy and 1 ore, etc), then find any "liars" in the graph (the solar plant is providing 4 energy, when it's maximum is 2), scale down their production and propagate the changes forward.  Once everything is resolved for the DAG, remove the terminal element (shipyard) from the graph and subtract the "current thruoghput" of each edge from the maximum throughput of the building, and then repeat the process for the next type of resource.  I thought I'd ask people far more intelligent than me if there's a better way. :)